# .env работает без python-donenv

Tags: python-3.x, pip, .env

Вопрос в следующем: для хранения настроек проекта используется пакет **Python-dotenv**. Создаём файл **.env** и помещаем в него нужные нам параметры.

Но тут обратил внимание на то, что чтение из файла **.env** происходит после **import os** и получается, что пакет **Python-dotenv** не нужен.
Версия python - 3.9, используется визуальное окружение pip

Почему так получается, что **Python-dotenv** не нужен? Или я что-то не понимаю?

Спасибо!

Comment: На основе чего вы сделали такой вывод? Добавьте код, с помощью которого вы тестировали своё предположение.

Comment: использую VC-code, виртуальное окружение создаю: python3 -m venv my_name_env
создаю просто некий файл test.py (внутри просто две строки import urllib.request  import os) и рядом с ним .env с любым параметром, допустим TOKEN="token_code"
запускаю режим debug и проверяю в консоли на каждом шаге: os.environ.get("TOKEN", None)
после выполнения import os команда os.environ.get("TOKEN", None) даёт мой токен из .env

что я не понимаю и почему срабатывает без Python-dotenv ?

Answer (score 0):

оказалось это возможно из-за встроенной функции VS Code:

> By default, the Python extension looks for and loads a file named .env in the current workspace folder, then applies those definitions. The file is identified by the default entry "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env" in your user settings (see General settings). You can change the python.envFile setting at any time to use a different definitions file.

[VS code документация](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file)

[stackoverflow.com/questions/](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59352225/12231818)